# Whats the Difference between a . and -> in calling a Method in C++

Tags: c++, methods

Can you tell me the difference between a . and -> call to a method in C++.

This code works fine, using both calling methods.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myclass
{
    public:
    string doSomething();
};


string myclass::doSomething()
{
    return "done something\n";
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    myclass c;
    std::cout << c.doSomething();

    myclass *c2;    
    std::cout << c2->doSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand the different between the 2 calls?  they both work?

Comment: Which book are you reading that doesn't explain the difference between these two?

Comment: Once I was asked this question giving Qt-consultancy at one big German communication company. A group of Java and JS-developers managed to develop in pretty short time a pretty impressive Qt/C++ based application without knowing the difference between . and -> ops. Speaks for effectiveness of Qt.

Comment: It may seem odd that your program works but it only does because the objects of `myclass` contain no data and aren't used in the `doSomething()` call. Thus, the compiler doesn't need to reference the class object. If the class had state information and your method used something in the class it would probably fail on a memory access.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The arrow operator is meant for calling a method from a pointer to an instance of an object.

The dot operator is meant for calling a method from a reference to an instance of an object, or on a locally defined object.

Your code would not compile if you reversed the operators on the two examples.

Comment: His code should not work in this state either, since he didn't assign any address to which the c2 pointer should point to. Also I think it's worth noting that both operators are member accessors and the '->' operator is, on top of the '.' operator, dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: Those args passed into main aalllmost look like C rather than c++

Comment: @ProXicT `c2` is a pointer in the OP's code. It's legal to apply that operator. Unless the class is virtual, there is no dereference happening.

Comment: @Cris It's an undefined behavior since he doesn't initialize the pointer.

Comment: @Cris The builtin arrow operator is defined to be equivalent to dereferencing the pointer and using the dot operator. He is dereferencing an invalid pointer according to the standard.

Comment: @TimSeguine: In C++ that is only true for built-in types. For classes, `operator->()` and `operator*()` are different functions. I am honestly not sure right now whether the standard dictates that the pointer will be dereferenced, but it certainly doesn't need to.

Comment: @Cris If like the OP's code you don't define either `operator*` or  `operator->` it uses the built in ones. Anyway the object that is being called with `operator->` is a built in pointer type here. You can't overload `operator->` for a built in pointer type.

Answer (score 11):

```
c2->doSomething();
```

is equivalent to:

```
(*c2).doSomething();
```

i.e. the pointer is being de-referenced before calling the method.

Check out Alf Steinbach's [pointer tutorial](https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=0B2oiI2reHOh4M2MzNzYwYzQtMGZkNC00NTljLWJiM2UtOGI0MmRkMTMyZGY4&pli=1) for more help.

Comment: -1 for cplusplus.com link. You should have suggested Alf Steinbach's [pointer tutorial](https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=0B2oiI2reHOh4M2MzNzYwYzQtMGZkNC00NTljLWJiM2UtOGI0MmRkMTMyZGY4&pli=1)

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav happy now? ;)

Comment: My only point was you should never recommend cplusplus.com tutorials. Lifted my downvote.

Comment: @Prasoon: Out of curiosity, what's wrong with cplusplus.com tutorials?

Comment: @Emile : Stuffs are not 100% correct. :-) It is not a reliable source.

Comment: +0 for mentioning Alf Steinbach's pointer tutorial. 171 pages on pointer-fetishism - no better way to discourage new developers using C/C++.

Answer (score 6):

> `myclass *c2;`
>       `std::cout << c2->doSomething();`

This is undefined behaviour. `c2` is not initialized.

You needed to write

```
myclass *c2 = &c;
c2->doSomething();
```

`c2->doSomething()` is semantically equivalent to `(*c2).doSomething()` which in-turn is same as `c.doSomething()`

**EDIT**

Check out Alf Steinbach's [pointer tutorial](https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=0B2oiI2reHOh4M2MzNzYwYzQtMGZkNC00NTljLWJiM2UtOGI0MmRkMTMyZGY4&pli=1)

Comment: I would like a Greasemonkey script that automatically upvotes @Prasoon Saurav on C++ questions.

Comment: @ackers : Undefined Behaviour means *anything* can happen. ASAT.

Comment: @ackers: Add a string member to the class and initialize it to "done something\n" in the constructor. Now try returning that instead.

Comment: @Benoit : Haha!! Its time to gain some rep now.

Comment: @ackers: depends on what optimizations your compiler makes. Here probably the compiler notices that the function does no depend on the state of your instance, then it needn't dereferencing the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

No, as posted, it won't work, because you do not initialize the *pointer* c2.

As for the syntax: Please refer to any introductory book on C++, which will explain this.

The short very version is, that the arrow operator `->` is a shortcut form for `(*c2).doSomething();`